# How to parse a c/c++ header with llvmlite in python

Tags: python, llvm, header-files

I'd like to parse a c and/or c++ header file in python using llvmlite.  Is this possible?  And if so, how do I create an IR representation of the header's contents?

Answer (score 0):

llvmlite is a python binding for LLVM, which is independent from C or C++ or any other language. To parse C or C++, one option is to use the python binding for libclang.